# How to change the style of a summary link web part in sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, branding

I created a summary link web part on my sharepoint 2007 page.
Now I see that If I select the style "Banded" for the group headers, they come up highlighted in grey.

[image]

Is there any way to change that background color into some other one? Maybe by changing some `.css` file or by adding some script in a content editor web part?

Answer (score 1):

You add a custom style sheet to you page using a content editor web part or customize the master page.
You will find some CSS snippet on my blog post on how to [turn summary link web part into an accordion](http://www.n8d.at/blog/turn-summary-link-web-part-into-an-accordion/).

What you need to customize is basically the groupheader:

```
.groupheader{
    background-color: #0072C6;
    color: white;
    font-size: 140%;
    padding: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 0.75em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.groupmarker:hover .groupheader{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #0597FF;
}

.dfwp-list{
    background-color: #0072C6;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 0.75em;
}
.dfwp-list .item:hover{
    background-color: #0597FF;
}
.dfwp-list .link-item a{
    margin-left: 2em;
    color: white;
}
```